# Detecting Safari 5 with Javascript

Tags: javascript, safari

How can i detect that the browser is Safari 5 or higher?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @meder: You think OP's up to something nefarious?

Comment: No, something fundamentally flawed. http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

Comment: something does not work unless safari 5 and up, so i want to exclude anything other than that....

Comment: Why don't you simply look whether the browser is able to do what you want it to do?

Comment: i cant, it just breaks safari 4, is not a feature issue is a way they handle things that braks my code - and there is no workaround besides not doing it...

Comment: Sure? What problem is it? You can use `try{...}catch(e){errorhandling code here}` to catch javascript errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to know if Safari is v5 or higher because of some feature.

In this case you can use also http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/

Comment: see inside the jquery code and take what you think is useful. see also http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good article on this topic:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

A bit more involved and with more code than maybe you are looking for, but it should certinaly help!

Comment: Fails on Opera 10.63. Tells me I'm running v9.8.