# How can I detect if a browser is Safari 5+ using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, safari

I need a method to detect that the browser is Safari 5 or higher - but the javascript should not rely on useragent since it can get overriden! Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need to prepare for the *exceedingly* rare case that the user agent gets spoofed? It stands to reason that somebody doing that to their browser can't expect sites to work correctly any more. There may be a way to do this using feature detection but the user-agent string is the most common way to detect a browser version.

Comment: It is much, much better to detect a specific feature you are interested in than to test a browser version.  What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I have a script that does not work in pre safari 5, so trying to check on a feature. Was relyong on Websocket...but wondered if someone had written something better

Comment: Similar question, with answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227982/detecting-safari-5-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

I have found PPK's [browser detection code](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) to be very reliable. It [utilizes navigator.vendor and navigator.userAgent](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2006/07/browser_detect.html).

Comment: I need something not relyin on user agent, as that can be modified by end user

Answer (score 0):

1. It's not possible to reliably detect the browser without accepting that the user agent can be modified by the end-user and / or the browser itself.
2. As a consequence of point 1. it is *almost* always best to use capabilities support detection (e.g. such as with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)).
3. As there *are* times when you need to specifically detect a browser, such as disabling or enabling a particular capability that is misreported / not detectable, e.g. File Drag and Drop in Safari 5

As an example, the following code provides a function `isFileDragAndDropSupported()` which makes use of the `isSafari5()` function to return that File Drag and Drop is supported on Safari 5 even though `window.FileReader` is not defined in Safari 5.

```
function isSafari5() {
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(' Safari/') && !navigator.userAgent.match(' Chrom') && !!navigator.userAgent.match(' Version/5.');
};

function isFileAPIEnabled () {
    return !!window.FileReader;
};

function isFileDragAndDropSupported() {
    var isiOS = !!navigator.userAgent.match('iPhone OS') || !!navigator.userAgent.match('iPad');
    return (Modernizr.draganddrop && !isiOS && (isFileAPIEnabled() || isSafari5()));
};
```

Note: Modernizr is required only for the isFileDragAndDropSupported() function. The isSafari5() function will work stand-alone.